# How can we see that $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^n(1-n)^3}{(n+1)(2n+1){2n \choose n}}=(\pi-1)(\pi-3) $?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, closed-form

I wonder will it help me so prove it if I was to decompose it into partial fractions?

Mathematica approves of the identity; it is converges. can anyone help me to prove it?

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^n(1-n)^3}{(n+1)(2n+1){2n \choose n}}=(\pi-1)(\pi-3)
> $$

Comment: *Mathematica* agrees with the identity.

Comment: @yurnero (+1) do you know how to go about proving it?

Comment: @yurnero: Mathematica *approves* of the identity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that, for $n\geq 0$, using the Euler beta function,
$$
\frac{2^n(1-n)^3}{(n+1)(2n+1){2n \choose n}}=-\frac{(n-1)^3}{n+1}\int_0^1(2x(1-x))^ndx. \tag1
$$ Then, one may write

> $$\begin{align}
> &\sum_0^\infty\frac{2^n(1-n)^3}{(n+1)(2n+1){2n \choose n}}
> \\\\&=-\sum_0^\infty\frac{(n-1)^3}{n+1}\int_0^1(2x(1-x))^ndx\\\\
> &=-\int_0^1\sum_0^\infty\frac{(n-1)^3}{n+1}(2x(1-x))^n \:dx\\\\
> &=\int_0^1\left(\frac{-7+34 x-82 x^2+96 x^3-48 x^4}{(1-2 x+2 x^2)^3}-\frac{4 \log(1-2 x+2 x^2)}{(1-x) x}\right)dx\\\\
> &=\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{-7+34 x-82 x^2+96 x^3-48 x^4}{(1-2 x+2 x^2)^3}\,dx}_{\large \color{blue}{3-4\pi}}+\underbrace{4\int_0^1-\frac{\log(1-2 x+2 x^2)}{(1-x) x}\,dx}_{\large \color{red}{\pi^2}}
> \\\\&=\color{blue}{3-4\pi}+\color{red}{\pi^2}
> \\\\&=(\pi-1)(\pi-3)
> \end{align}
> $$

as announced.

Comment: thank you, I have ask a lot of people and they could not prove it until now. I have a few more series please help me to answer. Again thank you so much Dr.

Comment: @ Olivier is there an alternative way of proving this sum without using integral technique?

Comment: @pisquare Yes. For example, one could have started with the standard result $$ \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{4^nx^{2n+2}}{(2n+1){2n \choose n}}=(\arcsin x)^2.$$ then differentiating it three times to get the factor $(n-1)^3$.

Comment: Differentiating three times that is a lot of work there. The first method is perfect. If I want to post another problem, do I do it here or open another page? The problem is also on sum like this.

Comment: A new page is better. Maybe you might want to give **some context** and **show your tries** in your question, as I see that some people want to close your question

Comment: When you say context, what do you mean by? Can you Give me an example of the above question.

Comment: @pisquare In fact, I really don't always understand why some people want to close certain questions. I don't really always agree with the fact that they vote to close some questions. So I can't give you a precise example. But in the case above, if you **show what you have tried by yourself** before asking for an answer here, maybe this would fit some expectations. But IMHO, I think you did not see even how to just begin to attack this problem, which might be classic but **not elementary...**

Comment: @Olivier Oloa Dear Sir, can you explain what happened when going from line 3 to line 4?

Comment: @OlivierOloa kindly if you can help me to proof another one of my maths sum on another page.

Comment: @cgiovanardi Sure. For the first integral, you integrate by parts: you get a fraction term plus an $\arctan$ term, giving $3-4\pi$. For the latter integral, a partial fraction decomposition followed by a series expansion, using $\int_0^a x^n \ln x \:dx=\frac{ (-1+\ln a+n \ln a)a^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}$ leads to $\pi^2$.

Comment: @pisquare You may follow Akos Somogyi steps: it looks fine.

Comment: @OlivierOloa your proof of first sum is nicely done and beautiful. I prefer you did it.

Comment: @OlivierOloa I failed to understand how:  
$$-\int_0^1\sum_0^\infty\frac{(n-1)^3}{n+1}(2x(1-x))^n \:dx\\\\=\int_0^1\left(\frac{-7+34 x-82 x^2+96 x^3-48 x^4}{(1-2 x+2 x^2)^3}-\frac{4 \log(1-2 x+2 x^2)}{(1-x) x}\right)dx\\\\$$
May you please kindly explain it to me?

Comment: @McCheng Sure. You may start with $\sum_0^\infty\frac{t^n }{n+1}=-\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}$, then by differentiating, using $(t\frac{d}{dt})(t^n)=n \times t^n$, thus  $(t\frac{d}{dt})^3(t^n)=n^3 \times t^n$, you end up with $t:=x(1-x)$.